# Why become smaller brace in empheq environment?

Tags: braces, empheq

I want to write simultaneous equations so I used empheq environment:

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
E_1 = V_1 + V_2 \\
V_2 - V_3 = 0
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
E_1 &= R_1I_1 + R_2I_2 \\
0   &= R_2I_2 - R_3I_3
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

However, left brace become small.

[image]

How can I make it the appropriate size?

Edit: Append preamble to code

Comment: Completing your code with a minimal preamble, I have no such problem. Just in case, what's your version of `empheq`?

Comment: I also tested with minimal preamble, and it seems that using jsarticle is the cause. In article, I have no such problem.
I write the report with Japanese, I must use jsarticle...

Comment: How should we know you're using jsarticle when you don't provide a full minimal example

Answer (score 2):

[cw non-answer I will delete once OP provides an example]

Please provide a small test file like the following that shows the problem.
I used `jsarticle` and `platex2e` but did not get the output that you show

[image]

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
E_1 = V_1 + V_2 \\
V_2 - V_3 = 0
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
E_1 &= R_1I_1 + R_2I_2 \\
0   &= R_2I_2 - R_3I_3
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```